# Design an op amp with gain of \$2\cdot V1+4\cdot V2-2\cdot V3-4\cdot V4\$

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was able to do the negative side of the op amp fairly easily, but I can't figure out how one would do the positive side.  Below is what the circuit looks like so far.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBEiWs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: Only one op amp can be used.

Comment: Av(+)=6+1=7...Av1=2, Av2=4 so **Vin(+)=(2V1+4V2)/7**. easy

Comment: Gain in units of Volts makes no sense.  And "2V1" instead of "2.1 V" is just obnoxious, if that's what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a summing amplifier problem. In the circuit shown, there should be a 400ohm resistor from the + input to ground to balance the feedback resistor, otherwise the currents don't add correctly.

The resistor ratios are OK, but the values should be MUCH higher, especially as a TL081 has a JFET input stage - otherwise the output is driving into a load of 400ohms. I suggest you use values of 10K, 20K and 40K.

Depending on the input voltages, you may need to look at the common mode range and/or the supply voltages - don't assume the opamp inputs are at ground, because in this circuit they ain't!

Answer (score 0):

Better you can put the V1 and V2 in series with 200 Ohm and 100 Ohm respectively in the inverting side of the OP-AMP and connect to non-inverting terminal to GND. Only thing is that, the negative terminal of V1 and V2 must be towards the inverting terminal and their positive terminal be grounded so that you are feeding -V1 and -V2 which gets inverted and become +V1 and +V2

Comment: Creative thinking, but based on the unwarranted assumption that the voltage sources can be reversed. Normally, all voltages are specified relative to a common reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ckt for the following question 
[image: 1]

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but you can only use one op amp.